# Android - WebView back button

Tags: android

I have a mirroring of a website in WebView and I would like that when I press the ** Back ** button on the Smartphone, I would go back to the previous page. Currently if I press the ** Back ** button on the Smartphone, the application is minimized (It stays in the background).
I do not know how to do this, can anyone help me?

**MainActivity**

```js
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        wv.loadUrl("https://www.xxxx.com.br");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setSupportZoom(false);
```

**Manifest**

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_stat_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new to the community. Sorry, I did not know how to use the search feature.
What is the procedure for deleting this topic, since the topic you posted helped in solving the problem: How to go back to previous page if pressed in WebView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override the onBackPressed method in your activity as below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    if(wv.canGoBack()){
        wv.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Use the above method inside your class, not outside.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //onCreate method

    //onBackPressed method

    //other methods

}
```

Comment: Returned with errors:

_Error:(31, 12) error: class, interface, or enum expected_
_Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details._

Comment: After the adjustments, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Saved me a headache, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this .

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Add `wv` as global data

```
private WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    wv.loadUrl("https://www.xxxxx.com.br");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setSupportZoom(false);

}
```

Comment: Returned with errors:

_Error:(33, 12) error: class, interface, or enum expected_

_Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'._

Comment: Use `wv` instead of `WebView` in your code .It was `WebView` Object .

Comment: As the error persists, I inserted the above code

Comment: You can try again.@Ever